# Case class immutable still able to change the parameter values

Tags: scala, immutability, case-class, constructor-overloading

I reviewed some code from a colleague and I came across a case class which is by default immutable.

the below case class can be changed so my question is how is this possible since case classes are immutable but in this construct i can change the case class parameters?

```
case class RegisterCustomerRequest(`first-name`: String,
                                   `last-name`: String,
                                   `house-details`: String,
                                   street: String,
                                   zipcode: String,
                                   city: String

    extends WcRequestData {

    def this(cardHolderData: CardHolderData,
           registrationCode: RegistrationCode,
           customerNumber: Long,
           cardDesignImageId: String) =
    this(`first-name` = cardHolderData.firstname,
         `last-name` = cardHolderData.lastname,
          street = cardHolderData.streetAndNumber,
          zipcode = cardHolderData.zipCode,
          city = cardHolderData.city,


       #   `house-details` = 
          s"${if (cardHolderData.employerName.contains("&")) 
          cardHolderData.employerName.replace("&" , " & ") else " / 
           "}${cardHolderData.employerName} ")#
    }
```

why can I define a `def this` method which can change the values of parameters. What is this construct good for is this good coding style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case class `RegisterCustomerRequest` is still immutable however it has an [auxiliary constructor](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s04.html) `def this` which allows it to be constructed in a different way. For example, given

```
case class User(name: String)

case class Foo(name: String) {
  def this(user: User) {
    this(name = user.name)
  }
}
```

we can construct `Foo` like so

```
Foo("picard")
```

or using the auxiliary constructor

```
new Foo(User("picard"))
```

In both cases the result is an immutable object. To confirm immutability try reassigning `name` after construction

```
(new Foo(User("picard"))).name = "worf" // Error: reassignment to val
```

As suggested by som-snytt, we can define `apply` method on companion object instead of auxiliary constructor like so

```
object Foo {
  def apply(user: User): Foo = Foo(user.name)
}
```

which enables the following construction

```
Foo(User("picard"))
```

Comment: On style, I'd expect an apply method on the companion instead of the second constructor. Of course the second ctor doesn't participate in "constructor pattern" in matches.